# REST API for getting project last analysis date?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

How do I get a project's last analysis time (the one you can see in the dashboard) with the REST API of SonarQube?

I am working with SonarQube 4.5.6, but if it's only available on later versions I'd still be interested in how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Resources API : https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources/index?metrics=date&format=json and look at the 'date' field to get the last analysis time.

Answer (score 13):

[EDIT] API relevant since SonarQube v6.3: *api/project_analyses/search*

[EDIT] Relevant API for SonarQube LTS v5.6.x: *api/projects?versions=true*

And since you mention later versions, since SonarQube 5.2:

> `api/ce/component` : get the pending tasks, in-progress tasks and the last executed task of a given component (usually a project) ([documentation](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/ce/component))

P.S.: `api/components/show` can be used to get the component ID from the project key

P.S.2 : here's a real-life example on [public SonarQube project](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube). First get the [component ID](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/components/show?key=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) then [query the component](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/ce/component?componentId=4e548e0d-6ce8-4d10-8e2c-c5474395d575) -> `"submittedAt": "2016-03-07T06:04:31+0100"` (slight difference with the dashboard value, due to the processing time on the scanner side)

Comment: Thanks for the info on the latest version!