# Delete old SonarQube projects with script

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube

I have a lot of unused and old sonarqube projects which I need to delete. With the Sonarqube API (Bulk-delete) I can only delete the projects by ID but I need to delete all projects which are older than 3 months. 
Is there a way to delete all projects older than 3 months maybe with a script? 
I can't delete them by hand because there are too many projects. 
I tried to google my problem but the only script I've found was a python script and I have no idea how to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube Web API lets you get the last analysis date of projects. All you need to do then is to combine that with your script to delete projects.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847110/rest-api-for-getting-project-last-analysis-date/35848691) for details on which Web API to use for querying the *last analysis date*.

Note that there's also a UI feature (covering your use-case) coming up in SonarQube 6.x series: [SONAR-4566](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4566) - *Bulk deletion: add a criterion "Last analysis more than X days old"*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that I have no script yet. I don't know how to write the right script for deleting the projects. Do you have an example?

Comment: You can start by using _curl_ to get familiar with the Web API (it's all just HTTP). And then use your favourite tool/language to write a script that performs a series of HTTP calls.

Comment: My idea was to build a JMeter script. There I can send the HTTP-Requests.