# How to get list of projects scanned in last day from Sonarqube v5.6.6 through WEB API?

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I am trying to find which teams are using SonarQube frequently. Hence I want to get list of projects scanned in last day from Sonarqube v5.6.6  through WEB API. 
I tried with api/measures/component_tree API. However I am not able to find string to be used for "Last Scanned date" metric. Can any one please help.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847110/rest-api-for-getting-project-last-analysis-date) for guidance on getting the last analysis date.

Comment: I tried that option,Relevant API for SonarQube LTS v5.6.x: api/projects?versions=true However it does not help. api/measures/ looks best as it allows to sort also. However I am not getting string to be used for "Last Scanned date" metric.

Comment: I got to know that api/projects/index?versions=last should work. However its giving me error as "ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 :" . May be need to optimize parameters passed to API. Planning to list all projects and query version date for each one. Is there any other better option?